# We deal 52 cards to 4 players, what is the probability that each player has an ace?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I saw on internet the answer is : $$\frac{13^4}{{52}\choose{4}} $$
but I don't intuitively understand it. So I tried another one that is : $$\frac{{52}\choose{13 \ 13 \ 13 \ 13}}{52!} \cdot 4!$$
Because we will divide **52 cards** into **4 groups** of **13 cards**, there is **52!** ways to shuffle the deck and **4!** ways to order the **4 aces**. But this doesn't give me a correct result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $13$ possible shufflings (of aces) for each group so it must be $13\cdot13\cdot13\cdot13=13^4$ and then we have $4!$ ways to order $4$ aces, and **all** the situations in which we shuffle the **cards** are $52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49$ (Because there are $4$ players and each time we give a card we have one fewer)  and if we continue we get; $$\frac{13^4\cdot4!}{52.51.50.49}=\frac{13^4}{52.51.50.49.\frac{1}{4!}}=\frac{13^4}{\binom{52}{4}}$$
I have also used the rule that $$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!\cdot r!}$$ in the case we plug in $n=52$ and $r=4$ we get $$\frac{52!}{48!\cdot4!}=\frac{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48!}{48!\cdot4!}$$ doing the cancellations and...

Answer (score 4):

Using multinomials. the answer is:

$$\frac{4!\cdot\binom{48}{12,12,12,12}}{\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}} = \frac{4!\,48!}{52!}\cdot \frac{13!\,13!\,13!\,13!}{12!\,12!\,12!\,12!} =\frac{13^4}{\binom{52}{4}}$$

Representing, as numerator on the left, a "pre-deal" of aces to each hand and the ways of distributing the remaining cards, and as denominator, the distribution without any pre-dealing.

The shuffling is not an extra factor, since the selection values already account for any possible ordering.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you understand the internet answer, as the logic is simple.

Imagine $13$ slots for each player, and focus on the aces (where the remaining cards go is irrelevant)

Ignoring order, the aces need to be placed in${\binom{13}1}^4 = 13^4$ ways,
against $\binom{52}4$ total ways, and thus the result.

And if you prefer multinomials, you will get the correct numerator by considering the distribution of non-aces and aces in each hand, viz.

$\dfrac{\binom{48}{12,12,12,12}\binom{4}{1,1,1,1}}{\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}}$

Comment: Nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

**Long answer:**

We first compute all the possible ways of dealing 13 cards to each player from a pool of 52. That is, we need to pick 13 cards out of 52 for the first player, 13 cards out of 39 for the second player (since we've already taken 13), 13 out of 26 for the third player (since we've already taken 26) and 13 out of 13 (since we've already taken 39):

So we have a sampling space $\Omega$ of size:

$$
\#\Omega = {52\choose 13} \cdot {39 \choose 13} \cdot {26 \choose 13} \cdot {13 \choose 13}\\
\#\Omega = \frac{52!}{13!(52-13)!} \cdot \frac{39!}{13!(39-13)!} \cdot \frac{26!}{13!(26-13)!} \cdot \frac{13!}{13!(13-13)!}\\
\#\Omega = \frac{52!\cdot 39! \cdot 26! \cdot 13!}{13!^4 \cdot 39! \cdot 26! \cdot 13! \cdot 0!}\\
\#\Omega = \frac{52!}{13!^4}
$$

But since we don't care about the order of each 13 cards package we divide by $4!$ so we end up with $$\#\Omega=\frac{52!}{13!^4\cdot 4!}$$

Now, let us define the event $A$ as all the possible distributions of 13 cards to each player such that each one have an ace. For the first player our sampling space changes since we want to discard 4 aces (one that is going to stay with the first player) out of the 52 cards and only pick 12 (since we are forcing the player to have an ace). For the second player we have 39 cards from which we'll only pick 12 out 36 (we take 3 aces out). For the third player we have 26 cards from which we'll only pick 12 out of 24 (we take 2 aces out). And for the last player we have 13 cards from which we pick 13. So the expression in terms of combinations looks like:
$$
\#A = {48 \choose 12} \cdot {36 \choose 12} \cdot {24 \choose 12} \cdot {13 \choose 13}\\
\#A = \frac{48!}{12!(48-12)!} \cdot \frac{36!}{12!(36-12)!} \cdot \frac{24!}{12!(24-12)!} \cdot \frac{13!}{13!(13-13)!}\\
\#A = \frac{48! \cdot 36! \cdot 24! \cdot 13!}{12!^3 \cdot 13! (36! \cdot 24! \cdot 12! \cdot 0!)}\\
\#A = \frac{48!}{12!^4}
$$

Finally, we have:

$$
P[A] = \frac{\#A}{\#\Omega} = \frac{48! \cdot 13!^4 \cdot 4!}{52! \cdot 12!^4}\\
P[A] \approx 0.105498
$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability for finding *one ace* has been *placed* among the *thirteen cards* of *each* of the four hands, when the *four aces* have been *randomly placed* among the *deck* of *fifty-two cards*,* is:$$\dfrac{\dbinom{13}1^4}{\dbinom{52}4}$$

---

An alternate way to evaluate this would be to take ways each player receives one ace and twelve other cards, and divide by the total ways each player receives thirteen cards.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{1,1,1,1}\dbinom{48}{12,12,12,12}}{\dbinom{52}{13,13,13,13}}$$

Which can easily be seen to give the same result.